# Compiler doesn't recognize Lombok Getter for overriden method

Tags: java, lombok

Assuming we have an interface `TestInterface` in an external artifact, that we cannot change:

```
public interface TestInterface {

    Boolean isTest();
    //more getter and setter methods
}
```

and an implementation of this interface, with more members corresponding to the parent interface. Lombok's generated getters/ setters are not recognized by the compiler, so I must add the actual getter method to make the following class compilable.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TestImplementation implements TestInterface {

    Boolean test;
    //more members
}
```

The compilation error is the standard error you get when a method of the interface is not implemented:

*my.package.TestImplementation is not abstract and does not override abstract method isTest() in my.package.TestInterface*

Supposing that Lombok's getters and setters are generated after compilation time, I don't understand why the normal call of getters (that are generated by Lombok) are compilable.

Comment: To be precise: you say, in the same project, you have **two** classes. One uses the annotations fine, but the class you are showing here, does give you compiler errors? That sounds strange, because the fact that some class implements some interface should really not interfere with what Lombok is doing.

Comment: Is this the case with _all_ Lombok annotations, or just with that specific getter on that class implementing this interface? Are you sure you peroperly "installed" Lombok into IntelliJ?

Comment: @GhostCat: Lombok getters are called all through the project and compile perfectly. It's only the case when the getter method is at the same time an override of the implemented interface that doesn't work. Yes, the class I am showing gives compilation error.

Comment: @tobias_k Lombok works, getters and setters normally compile, it's only the override that makes problems. The fix is to write the getter, but than I don't need Lombok anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be that for a field `Boolean test`, Lombok will generate a method `Boolean getTest()`, instead of `Boolean isTest()` as required by the interface. Only if the property is `boolean test` then you get a `boolean isTest()` method, but then the return type does not match the interface.

So there seems to be no way around implementing the `isTest` method yourself.

Comment: Thanks for bringing light into this. Tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Answer accepted. I can live with writing the method myself and using the primitive type wherever I have the choice.

Comment: The underlying reason is the BeanSpec of Java, which requires `Boolean` getters to have the `get` prefix (other than `boolean`s).

Answer (score 1):

Considering Java Bean Naming Conventions, the getter for your (wrapper object) field of type Boolean, should be `getTest`. Hence Lombok is doing "the right" thing.
You could either change your field type to be of primitive boolean to get the desired method or adjust your interface to match the Java Bean Naming Convention.